# How do i get the x,y coordinate for a screen touch?

Tags: android

Is there a simple way to obtain the x,y coordinate whenever someone touches the screen while my app is running?  Just looking to store them in some integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` and then call `event.getX()` and `event.getY()` to get the coordinate positions of where the user touched [they will be floats].

Answer (score 0):

its very simple to get the coordinates position where the user touched on screen.

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // MotionEvent object holds X-Y values
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        String text = "You click at x = " + event.getX() + " and y = " + event.getY();
        Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```