# How to know the screen position where the user touched the screen?

Tags: android

In my app I draw an image covering the entire screen.
I want to now how can I know where the user touched the screen?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i get the x,y coordinate for a screen touch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637827/how-do-i-get-the-x-y-coordinate-for-a-screen-touch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered here: [How do i get the x,y coordinate for a screen touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637827/how-do-i-get-the-x-y-coordinate-for-a-screen-touch/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of one of my games that does this.  There are different ways to do it, but here I did it by subclassing View:

```
public class WorldView extends View {
   ...

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    Log.d(TAG,"touch event "+action+" x="+event.getX()+" y="+event.getY());
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
    {
        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();
        Log.d(TAG,"setting target to "+x+","+y);
    }
    else
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);

    return true;
}
```